# All logins fail on Craft CMS 3 after code redeploy and database restore

Tags: login, deployment

**Background:**

AWS deployed Craft site.
I pushed an update to the php version (7.0.32 to 8.0x) the container was running on along with an upgrade to Craft (Craft Pro 3.5.15.1 to 3.7.42) and several plugins.  The site deployed on an identical dev site, but failed on prod.

**Problem:**

We rolled back the code and the database to the last known good values from 30 hours previous.  The site loads and functions as expected, but now all admin area logins fail.

The response to the ajax login request is:
`{"error":"A server error occurred."}`

The response headers are as follows:

```
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
content-length: 36
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 14 May 2022 17:28:55 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
via: 1.1 4a1233fa0e4a8dfe989f355fdbeb9b14.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: aoxRAhK-ldNXNWnJKtEH2_x0VHj4tEBgisl3h8XE5_t9CD-u9BkJiQ==
x-amz-cf-pop: DFW53-C1
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-powered-by: Craft CMS
x-robots-tag: none
:authority: example.com
:method: POST
:path: /index.php?p=cube/actions/users/login
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 61
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1648024404.1652295736; _fbp=fb.1.1652295736733.917977208; 1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_username=d98c860c8cbda90bac21c88076b34a0a22267d290696b6df1c34b0de4d857312a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A41%3A%221031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5_username%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A13%3A%22stacy.vlasits%22%3B%7D; Craft-ce3ffcac-3b61-4159-907c-68ff708ebbd7:siteId=1; CraftSessionId=e7521bcf52bda2f7ddb8a1c2765d18fa; CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN=e5385190a15e0eb37cc3465401384255f7d00bea35a7753bb1b31c408d65f25da%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A16%3A%22CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A40%3A%22meRZGv5sPwShEJ-eaSDIiwyNQg4rLgdTQ_G4JEUm%22%3B%7D; _gid=GA1.2.2044167146.1652479882
origin: https://example.com
referer: https://example.com/cube/login
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36
x-csrf-token: HppJJ_VCrT79J7wicjVIuFZUZM0TReLRmxwG2dQEcVTstkv68j6YxXP_G32yNJhNrVDvSjd_Zd03ByCEejKbn8p7MquYYxUAvekMzrh7zag=
x-registered-asset-bundles: ,doublesecretagency\cpcss\web\assets\CustomAssets,craft\web\assets\cp\CpAsset,craft\web\assets\axios\AxiosAsset,craft\web\assets\d3\D3Asset,craft\web\assets\elementresizedetector\ElementResizeDetectorAsset,craft\web\assets\garnish\GarnishAsset,yii\web\JqueryAsset,craft\web\assets\jquerytouchevents\JqueryTouchEventsAsset,craft\web\assets\velocity\VelocityAsset,craft\web\assets\jqueryui\JqueryUiAsset,craft\web\assets\jquerypayment\JqueryPaymentAsset,craft\web\assets\datepickeri18n\DatepickerI18nAsset,craft\web\assets\picturefill\PicturefillAsset,craft\web\assets\selectize\SelectizeAsset,craft\web\assets\fileupload\FileUploadAsset,craft\web\assets\xregexp\XregexpAsset,craft\web\assets\fabric\FabricAsset,craft\web\assets\iframeresizer\IframeResizerAsset,craft\web\assets\login\LoginAsset
x-registered-js-files: ,https://example.com/cpresources/1889e411/axios.min.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/cf77d456/d3.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/62e86375/element-resize-detector.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/4d78c880/jquery.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/c676c8c5/jquery.mobile-events.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/5cf73ffd/velocity.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/fccac3d0/garnish.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/125ea458/jquery-ui.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/40d09015/jquery.payment.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/c1d2f407/picturefill.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/95acd983/selectize.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/d93af5f9/jquery.fileupload.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/9fc09d09/xregexp-all.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/e98c17ee/fabric.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/d599caee/iframeResizer.js?v=1652522427,https://example.com/cpresources/9383fcca/js/Craft.min.js?v=1652522426,https://example.com/cpresources/2657649f/login.min.js?v=1652522427
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: storage logs? change to dev mode to get a usefull error message